# Use of Parameter in SQLite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, parameters, windows-ce

I have my `SQLite` db storing my info and it works ok. However I want to use `Parameter`.

I modify this line to set the `values` and **works ok**:

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO users ("+data[0]+", "+data[1]+") VALUES (@4,@5);");
p = new SQLiteParameter("@4", System.Data.DbType.String);
p.Value = data[4];
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
p = new SQLiteParameter("@5", System.Data.DbType.String);
p.Value = data[5];
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

**ERROR**: But if I want to use `Parameter` to the column's names it say there's a `syntax error near "@0"`:

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO users (@0, @1) VALUES (@4,@5);");
    p = new SQLiteParameter("@0", System.Data.DbType.String);
    p.Value = data[0];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    p = new SQLiteParameter("@1", System.Data.DbType.String);
    p.Value = data[1];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    p = new SQLiteParameter("@4", System.Data.DbType.String);
    p.Value = data[4];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    p = new SQLiteParameter("@5", System.Data.DbType.String);
    p.Value = data[5];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

It's possible to use `Parameter` in this case? What's wrong with the code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a good reason your column names are dependent on user data?

Comment: @notfed. Yes, In my db are like 20 columns and I must insert data only in 5 columns selected by the user

Comment: Side Note: Avoid String.Format at all costs!! Def String.Concat in this case..

Comment: @banging thanks for the advice. I'll check your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot parameterize column names. first approach is ok.

OR you can send all these as parameters to stored procedure and build query dynamically at db level and execute.

Comment: Same with table names and probably all the other database objects!